# What is the equation for action-value Q(s,a) in Monte Carlo Off-policy Prediction problem?

Tags: monte-carlo, reinforcement-learning

This is a question (Exercise 5.6) from Page 108 in Sutton's RL book (2nd edition). In Chapter 5, the authors mentioned that the state value function after importance-scaling is given by the following:

$$
V(s)  \doteq \frac{\sum_{t\in\mathcal{T(s)}} \rho_{t:T(t)-1}G_t}{\sum_{t\in\mathcal{T(s)}} \rho_{t:T(t)-1}}
$$

The question asks for an equation analogous to the above equation but for action-value $Q(s,a)$ given returns generated using the behavior policy $b$.

While some people were kind enough to share their answers on Github:
$$
Q(s,a)  \doteq \frac{\sum_{t\in\mathcal{T(s,a)}} \rho_{t+1:T(t)-1}G_t}{\sum_{t\in\mathcal{T(s,a)}} \rho_{t+1:T(t)-1}}
$$

But I couldn't figure this out. Why does $\rho$ starts from $t+1$ in $Q(s,a)$?

I appreciate if you could explain this to me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does $\rho$ starts from $t+1$ in $Q(s,a)$?

In general, when accounting for *any* stochastic effect in estimates of value functions in reinforcement learning, you need to pay attention to which random elements you have already conditioned on.

When you are estimating $Q(s_t,a_t)$ then you are looking at all the events that happen *after* choosing $a_t$. It does not matter at that point which policy chose the action in time step $t$, so there is no need to correct for probability ratios between behaviour and target policy. This is unlike estimates for $V(s_t)$ where you do care about differences in policy affecting which action will happen on time step $t$.

The target policy could have a probability of zero for selecting $a_t$, and you can still update your estimate of $Q(s_t,a_t)$ - if this were not possible then the agent could never learn about alternative actions to the greedy policy.

Single-step Q learning is an interesting case where because you have already conditioned on the action $a_t$ at time step $t$ and are using the target policy (greedy action choice) to establish $a_{t+1}$ at time step $t+1$, then there is no need to use importance sampling.

Comment: Thanks for your explainations.